# Perform a merge on two strings

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to build a collaborative doc editor and implement operational transformation. Imagine we have a string that is manipulated simultaneously by 2 users. They can only add characters, not remove them. We want to incorporate both of their changes.

The original string is: `catspider`

The first user does this: `cat<span id>spider</span>`

The second user does this: `c<span id>atspi</span>der`

I'm trying to write a function that will produce: `c<span id>at<span id>spi</span>der</span>`

The function I've written is close, but it produces `c<span id>at<span i</span>d>spider</span>` [codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpbKxR?editors=1111)

```
String.prototype.splice = function(start, newSubStr) {
    return this.slice(0, start) + newSubStr + this.slice(start);
};

function merge(saved, working, requested) {
    if (!saved || !working || !requested) {
        return false;
    }

    var diffSavedWorking = createDiff(working, saved);
    var diffRequestedWorking = createDiff(working, requested);

    var newStr = working;

    for (var i = 0; i < Math.max(diffRequestedWorking.length, diffSavedWorking.length); i++) {

        //splice does an insert `before` -- we will assume that the saved document characters
        //should always appear before the requested document characters in this merger operation
        //so we first insert requested and then saved, which means that the final string will have the
        //original characters first.

        if (diffRequestedWorking[i]) {

            newStr = newStr.splice(i, diffRequestedWorking[i]);

            //we need to update the merge arrays by the number of 
            //inserted characters.
            var length = diffRequestedWorking[i].length;
            insertNatX(diffSavedWorking, length, i + 1);
            insertNatX(diffRequestedWorking, length, i + 1);
        }

        if (diffSavedWorking[i]) {
            newStr = newStr.splice(i, diffSavedWorking[i]);

            //we need to update the merge arrays by the number of 
            //inserted characters.
            var length = diffSavedWorking[i].length;
            insertNatX(diffSavedWorking, length, i + 1);
            insertNatX(diffRequestedWorking, length, i + 1);
        }
    }
    return newStr;
}

//arr1 should be the shorter array.
//returns inserted characters at their 
//insertion index.
function createDiff(arr1, arr2) {
    var diff = [];
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        diff[i] = "";
        while (arr2[j] !== arr1[i]) {
            diff[i] += arr2[j];
            j++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    var remainder = arr2.substr(j);
    if (remainder) diff[i] = remainder;
    return diff;
}

function insertNatX(arr, length, pos) {
    for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        arr.splice(pos, 0, "");
    }
}

var saved =     'cat<span id>spider</span>';
var working =   'catspider';
var requested = 'c<span id>atspi</span>der';

console.log(merge(saved, working, requested));
```

Would appreciate any thoughts on a better / simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: This might be more appropriate on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The problem lies in the detection of inserted fragments. catspider and cat<span id>spider gives **cat** < **sp** an **id** > spid **er** and this is probably not what you want... it should return **cat** <span id> **spider**...

Comment: I'm actually thinking the problem is not solvable as is. Consider the changes `catsspider` and `catsopider`. There's no way to know just by looking at the strings whether the merge result should be `catsospider` or `catssopider`. I think I need to create a temporary string with special delimiters for the inserted characters.